# Division by zero when calculating increment/decrement percentage

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am trying to know if a value ($x) is 50% bigger or smaller than a value ($y).

I am doing this:

```
$diff = ($x - $y) / $x;

if (abs($diff) > 0.5) {

echo "it's happening";
}
```

The problem is when $x is 0.  How can I solve that cleanly? Notice that I want to be able to calculate the increment/decrement even when the value is 0.

Comment: check whether $x is not equal to 0 before calculate $diff

Comment: Prasath, but if is zero I still want to calculate if the increment/decrement is bigger than 50%

Comment: If $x is zero, then (unless $y is zero as well, in which case the difference is 0%) $x is always infinitely smaller (or infinitely larger if $y is negative) than $y.... the difference will __always__ be more than 50%

Comment: Mark Baker, correct. But how would I calculate that difference?

Comment: why do you divide by $x, shouldn't it be $y if you want to make the comparison with respect to $y ?

Comment: Perhaps you could use this formula instead: `($x / $y - 1) * 100 = difference in %`. So this calculates how much % difference there is from `$y` to `$x`. I believe that is what you want?

Comment: @Hommer Smith - if $x == 0 && $y == 0) { $diff = 0; } elseif ($x == 0) { $diff = 'INFINITY'; } else { .... use your formula here; }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out ' if a value ($x) is 50% bigger or smaller than a value ($y).', then you should divide the difference by $y instead of $x. And when $y equals to zero, then any value (+ve or -ve) is infinitesimally larger or smaller than $y. No finite calculation is possible there.

Comment: Are you sure about dividing by $y? If I want to find out if $x is bigger/smaller than $y?

Comment: try to find out how much bigger in percentage  is 10  than 5 ?